# Finding side of a triangle, given two sides and angle bisector

Tags: geometry

Given : $\triangle ABC$, $AB=7$, $AC=9$, the angle bisector of $\angle BAC$ passes through $BC$ in point $D$ such that $AD = BD$, find $BC$. Here is the drawing:
[image]

I have no idea where to start with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{BD}{DC}=\frac{AB}{AC}\Rightarrow BD=7x=AD, CD=9x$$
$$AD^2=AC\cdot AB-BD \cdot CD$$
$$49x^2=63-63x^2$$
$$112x^2=63$$
$$x^2=\frac{9}{16}$$
$$x=\frac34$$
$$BC=16x=16\cdot \frac 34=12$$

Comment: By a tedious computation, I got $\tan\alpha=\sqrt5/2$, and you got $\cos\alpha=2/3$, so I have to agree. But I don’t see the reason for your first ratio. Could you remind me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem

Comment: Oh yes, now I remember seeing this relatively late in life; but Mrs. Stewart didn’t teach us that one. Thanks.